# Apache htaccess rules converting to Nginx rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I need to translate some htaccess rules for the nginx server,

my htaccess was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

i've translated this part

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

that looks like

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
  set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
  set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 last;
}
```

is it ok?

Then I need to translate the second part of the htaccess (showed above).

How can I translate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if (!-f $request_filename){
>    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
> }
> if (!-d $request_filename){
>    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
> }
> if ($rule_0 = "21"){
>    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /bitfungus/index.php/$1 last;
> }
> ```
>
> is it ok?`

No, it's ugly. Nginx isn't apache, you should not use rewrites where you don't actually need them (in about 95% cases you don't need rewrites in nginx).

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Correct:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /bitfungus/index.php$uri;
```

Comment: ok thx, and what about the rest ..mod_gzip and mod_expires (from apache) ?

Comment: Read the documentation and write your own rules: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html and http://nginx.org/r/expires